# Wrapping Boost ptree to keep a map of loaded xml tag

Tags: c++, templates, boost

As mentioned in title:

```
struct AXmlConfigurator : private boost::noncopyable {
protected:
    std::string configuration_file_;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> parameters_;
    ptree ptree_;

public:

    AXmlConfigurator(const std::string &argConfigurationFile) :
        configuration_file_(argConfigurationFile) {
        read_xml(configuration_file_, ptree_);
    }

    ~AXmlConfigurator() {}

    template<typename Type> inline
    Type get(const std::string & argPath, Type argDefault) const {
        Type value = ptree_.get<Type>(argPath, argDefault);
        parameters_.insert(std::pair<std::string,std::string>(argPath, value));
        return value;
    }

    template<class Type , class Translator> inline
    typename boost::enable_if<detail::is_translator<Translator>, Type>::type
    get(const std::string &argPath, const Type &argDefault, Translator tr) const {
        Type value = ptree_.get(argPath, argDefault);
        parameters_.insert(std::pair<std::string,std::string>(argPath, value));
        return value;
    }
    void logConfiguration() {
        for(std::map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator it = parameters_.begin() ; it != parameters_.end() ; ++it) {
            std::cout << (*it).first << " => " << (*it).second << std::endl;
        }
    }

};
```

I want to wrap boost::property_tree::ptree to store the parameters/values as strings into a map and display them afterward through logConfiguration.

The probleme is that map's insert does not accept value as a string because value type is unspecified...

I'm out of ideas, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please show the actual error you're getting.  If I understand the question, you're having trouble understanding what the error is telling you.  *So are we*.  :)

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping :), I had various errors over everything I tryed while inserting to this std::map, and I can understand what they are related to... the map waits for std::pair<std::string, std::string> while I'm provided an unspecified type... So my question is more like: How would you achieve this goal ?

Comment: It not clear *why* you want `get` to work on unspecified types instead of `std::string`.  Should we assume that you're asking how to convert an unspecified type to a `std::string`?

Comment: As you can see here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/tutorial.html, `get` is templated and I want to wrap it by loosing its template aspect. So yes, I need more or less a way to get that unspecified `value` accepted by my map...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here is what I finally did, it's very hugly, but I'm not after performance on this thing, so it'll do the job:

```
template<typename Type>
Type get(const std::string & argPath, Type argDefault) {
    std::string value = "a";
    try {
        value = ptree_.get<std::string>(argPath);
    } catch(ptree_bad_path &e) {
        return argDefault;
    }

    parameters_.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(argPath,value));
    return ptree_.get<Type>(argPath, argDefault);
}

template<class Type , class Translator>
typename boost::enable_if<detail::is_translator<Translator>, Type>::type
get(const std::string &argPath, const Type &argDefault)  {
    std::string value = "";
    try {
        value = ptree_.get<std::string>(argPath);
    } catch(ptree_bad_path &e) {
        return argDefault;
    }

    parameters_.insert(std::pair<std::string,std::string>(argPath, value));
    return ptree_.get(argPath, argDefault);
}
```

I just retrieve the parameter as a string as Drew suggested, just that I catch the exception if needed and return the default value...

Answer (score 0):

Since you *need* the data to be a `std::string`, change:

```
    Type value = ptree_.get<Type>(argPath, argDefault);
```

to:

```
    std::string value = ptree_.get<std::string>(argPath, argDefault);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I tryed that already :), probleme is that `argDefault` is a `Type` while `get` needs a `std::string` as default value if it's templated to `std::string`, thanks again for you help tho

Comment: @Syffys Then this question probably doesn't relate directly to Boost ptree.  You've written a function with an argument `argDefault` and you need that data to be a `std::string`.

Comment: I understand, but my point is that ptree retrieves the data from an xml file obviously as a string, so there must be a way to get a string from this type...